# Passing For Loop Variable into AJAX Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, scope

I have an issue with passing my for loop index variable into ajax success function.. I know this is a duplicate, but I've tried several other solutions that I've found and none seem to work for me..

Anyway, I have this code right here :

```
embeds = document.getElementsByClassName('kcode');
for (i = 0, l = embeds.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (typeof embeds[i] != 'undefined' && typeof embeds[i].classList != 'undefined' && !embeds[i].classList.contains('filled')) {
        embeds[i].classList.add('filled');
        var embed = window.intext[embeds[i].getAttribute('data-k-kid')];
        if (embed) {
            embeds[i].classList.add('embed');
            switch (embed.type.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'sport_plugin':
                    if(sportData.selectedType.name == "Ranking Table") {
                        (function(i) {
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: url,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function(response) {
                                    var content = '';
                                    if (table.name == "Western Conference" || table.name == "Eastern Conference") {
                                        content+= '</div>';
                                        embeds[i].innerHTML = content;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        })(i);
                    }
                break;
                default:
                embeds[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            embeds[i].classList.remove('kcode');
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve -

I want to pass the embeds variable and the `i` variable of `for` loops index into my ajax response, so I could set the `innerhtml` of embeds[i] after the response is finished. I tried wrapping the ajax `function in (function (i) {})(i);` closure but it didint help. Any ideas? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I think i variable should be global in that scope, so I would try to use it like this:

```
case 'sport_plugin':
                if(sportData.selectedType.name == "Ranking Table") {
                  jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                      var content = '';
                      if (table.name == "Western Conference" || table.name == "Eastern Conference") {
                        content+= '</div>';
                        embeds[i].innerHTML = content;
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a callback success function for the ajax. Before the ajax call. Something like this

```
var successCallback = function() {
    var content = '';
    if (table.name == "Western Conference" || table.name == "Eastern Conference") {
        content+= '</div>';
        this.embeds[this.i].innerHTML = content;
    }
};

successCallback.i = i;
successCallback.embeds = embeds;
```

Note the "this." in front of the i.
And then your ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: successCallback
});
```

I have not tried it but it might work

Comment: Hi,

Thank You for Your reply, unfortunately it didin't solve my problem. 

I'm still getting the "Can't set innerhtml for undefined"..

Comment: Then try the same concept for embeds as well. successCallback.embeds = embeds. Then in the callback function this.embeds[this.i].innerHTML = content

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself, nontheless thanks for all the help and replies!

I simply used this function for getting my data, instead of usual ajax response..

```
_get = {

'sync': function (url) {
    var xhr = typeof XDomainRequest != 'undefined' ? new XDomainRequest() : new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, false);
    xhr.send(null);
    console.log('sync url ' + url);
    //console.log(xhr.responseText); return {};
    var data = {};
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    }
    return data;
}
};
```

And then just

```
var response = _lr.get.sync(url);
```